# Change Hibernate xml mapping file without recompile and rebuild app

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, configuration, hibernate-mapping

The purpose is to provide to my application two different version of an entity depending on the environment server.
So I created Entity1.hbm.xml and Entity2.hbm.xml and load them with `<mapping resource="fr/myproject/config/pojos/Entity1.hbm.xml"/>` in the hibernate.cfg.xml related on a key written in my application.properties file.

I use as well this as the configuration in the Java code :

```
public class HibernateUtil {
 
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    public HibernateUtil() {
        
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
 
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

But I'm facing a problem in the process. When I update a hbm.xml file with new or updated property on the entity before the launch of the application on Tomcat it doesn't work unless I recompile and rebuild my app.

Do we need to recompile/rebuild app when a change is made on configuration file like xml ? I thought xml files were independant of the build we can make modification any time we want.